# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kie/api/KieServices$Factory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark, drools

I have created a spark maven java project in eclipse.

I have added all the drools binaries as External jars.

in my pom.xml I have defined below dependencies for drools.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

In my code I have used below class :

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
```

When I am running this program using `spark-submit` command

```
spark-submit --class Transformation --master local "C:\Users\xyz\SparkWorkspace\Transformation\target\Transformation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

I am getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kie/api/KieServices$Factory
        at Transformation.main(Transformation.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:87
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 11 more
```

I am not able to find any reason for same, as I have added required libs and maven dependencies.

Can anyone help here? do I need to setup anything for drools in spark environment?

**EDIT**

under .m2 folder also I can see these maven dependencies jar files.

and using decompiler I checked that Factory static inner class is also present in KieServices interface.

Then why at runtime this error is occurring?

Comment: delete m2 folder once and try again.

Comment: add `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>` in your pom.xml file and check

Comment: I have tried those things but issue is when I am running spark-submit command while executing the jar it is not able to find the class.